# QGIS - Get the attributes of the neighbors, if not NULL

Tags: qgis, expression, neighbour

I would like to extrapolate information contained in a point layer by searching if the attributes of the neighbor feature are not NULL.

The point layer is called 'centroïd_extrapolation'
I'm using this expression to get the neighbors's "id" attributes.

```
with_variable(
    name:='current_id',
    value:="id",
    expression:=aggregate(
        layer:='[T]_Grid_100x100_A',
        aggregate:='concatenate',
        expression:= to_string(id),
        concatenator:=',',
        filter:=intersects($geometry, buffer(geometry(@parent),100)) AND "id" != @current_id
    )
)
```

But, after that, I don't know how to proceed.
I've been testing things since a few hours, and I have no idea on how I can manage to check in the same layer if the "id" is contained in another row of the same layer (in the field "Overlay_2").

I attach a picture to show what I would like to do :

[image: Example]

As you can see on the picture, I would like to find the "id" (25723) in the field "Overlay_2". When it is found, in 3 cases, I would like to take the attributes (like "Mang_dens") from '25723' to the other ones that have been found, except if their attributes are already filled (not NULL) (like the second to the last row).

I guess I will have to repeat the same operation to each attribute I want to get.

Comment: This is a classical case to use `overlay_nearest()` function: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/de/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-nearest. In rest, at least to me, the question is unclear, I don't really understand what you try to do...

Comment: As you advised, I used this expression to get information for each field I need. It worked. The expression : array_to_string(overlay_nearest('Layer',"Field", limit:=20, max_distance:= 250)